# How to handle external dependencies in modules loaded at runtime using SystemJS?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular8, systemjs

I am trying to load external modules in angular at runtime using systemJS.

```
import { System } from 'systemjs';
declare const SystemJS: System;

import * as angularCore from '@angular/core';

// Why do we need to do this?
SystemJS.set('@angular/core', SystemJS.newModule(angularCore));
```

Loading the module at runtime:

```
SystemJS.import(`${url}`).then((module) => {
        return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.externalModule).then(compiled => {
            const factory = compiled.componentFactories[0];
            this.container.createComponent(factory);
        });
```

**If my external module has some dependencies which are not available in my main app, how will I load those dependencies?**

For ex,
if I use

```
import { abc } from 'xyz';
```

in my external module, when 'xyz' is not present as a dependency in my main app, the server responds with an `error 404 http://localhost:4200/xyz not found`. So how can I make sure that these dependencies are also available during runtime.

I am importing the `external.umd.js` using systemjs, and AFAIK, the UMD file does not bundle the dependencies with the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try using webpack to bundle dependencies that are not available in your main app.
See the link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/